# Two-color background to show two columns

Tags: html, css, angular-flex-layout

I have a form that should look like it has 2-columns by having different colors on each column. The form layout is not distinctly divided into 2 different columns. How do I put a background with 2 different colors? The Optimized Tunnel should be `lightgray` and the Adjusted Tunnel is `lightblue`.
Thank you!

```html
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
  <div class="wrapper" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="90">
    <div fxLayout="row">
      <div fxFlex="50" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <h4>Optimized Tunnel Sizing</h4>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="50" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <h4>Adjusted Tunnel Sizing</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row">
      <ul fxLayout="column" fxFlex="55">
        <li class="form-row" fxLayout="row">
          <label>Final Sizing Input</label>
        </li>
        <li fxLayout="row">
          <label class="coil-limit-label" for="fpmLimit">Coil/Filter FPM Limit</label>
          <input class="coil-limit-input" id="fpmLimit" [value]="this.FPMLimit" type="number">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end">
      <ul fxLayout="column" fxFlex="70">
        <li class="form-row">
          <label fxLayoutAlign="start"></label>
          <label fxLayoutAlign="start">Overrides</label>
        </li>
        <li class="form-row">
          <label for="casingHeightOverride" fxLayoutAlign="start">Casing Height</label>
          <input id="casingHeightOverride" [value]="65" type="number" fxLayoutAlign="start">
        </li>
        <li class="form-row">
          <label for="casingWeightOverride" fxLayoutAlign="start">Casing Width</label>
          <input id="casingWeightOverride" [value]="75" type="number" fxLayoutAlign="start">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: use gradient background-color.

Comment: The gradient does can't have distinct separation of colors. Right?

Comment: [They can.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients#Creating_hard_lines)

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to use different classes for both columns and set different background color to both classes respectively lightgray and lightblue? like below code

```css
.column1{
  background-color:lightgray;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  padding:15px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.column2{
  background-color:lightblue;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
      <div class="wrapper" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="90">
        <div fxLayout="row">
          <div fxFlex="50" class="column1" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <h4>Optimized Tunnel Sizing</h4>
          </div>
          <div fxFlex="50" class="column2" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <h4>Adjusted Tunnel Sizing</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row"  class="column1">
          <ul fxLayout="column" fxFlex="55">
            <li class="form-row" fxLayout="row">
              <label>Final Sizing Input</label>
            </li>
            <li fxLayout="row">
              <label class="coil-limit-label" for="fpmLimit">Coil/Filter FPM Limit</label>
              <input class="coil-limit-input" id="fpmLimit" [value]="this.FPMLimit" type="number">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end"  class="column2">
          <ul fxLayout="column" fxFlex="70">
            <li class="form-row">
              <label fxLayoutAlign="start"></label>
              <label fxLayoutAlign="start">Overrides</label>
            </li>
            <li class="form-row">
              <label for="casingHeightOverride" fxLayoutAlign="start">Casing Height</label>
              <input id="casingHeightOverride" [value]="65" type="number" fxLayoutAlign="start">
            </li>
            <li class="form-row">
              <label for="casingWeightOverride" fxLayoutAlign="start">Casing Width</label>
              <input id="casingWeightOverride" [value]="75" type="number" fxLayoutAlign="start">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would like the colors to fill the entire columns.